# Search all <img ...> in database tables that are children of <container class="this" .... and add a class

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, replace

I have many many pages on my website. Among those numerous pages I have a lot a html tables with the class name : class="scrollable"
I'd like to add the class="nolazy" to all the images contained by all the <table class="scrollable"...> throughout my website.
It would be painful and long doing that by hand page after page. I don't even know how I could  easily spot list the pages which have a  with images inside.

I made my website with a custom template in wordpress

- Can I do this with a plugin (would be the best) ?
- Can I do this with a sql query ?

Thanks for your help,

François

Comment: Just my quick 2 cents, i think you will hardly (read like never) achieve this via just SQL. Plugins? i don't really know if there's something so specific for your case. If this would be a task assigned to me i would just write a custom plugin, querying all the pages inside WP and use some HTML DOM parser to find what i need and save the content back :)

Comment: Hi Diego thanks for the answer. I have no idea how I would write a custom plugin, querying all the pages inside WP and use some HTML DOM parser to find a change what I need. Would you know a tutorial I could follow to do what I need ?

Answer (score 1):

I'll post this as an answer if that's what you are looking for.

Wordpress plugin guide:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/
- https://www.wpbeaverbuilder.com/creating-wordpress-plugin-easier-think/

Querying wordpress page:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_pages/

HTML DOM Parser:

- https://github.com/Rct567/DomQuery

Mix it all together and you will for sure achieve the result :D

Comment: Great. it's much clearer how works an html parser. Just to confimr what I understand. To install the html parser I must download the github folder you linked somewhere on my server, enter my server by the terminal window and run this command line :
$ composer require myserverroot/subfolderonmyserver/rct567/dom-query
Is that it ?
thanks a lot

Comment: You are confused, if you want to use composer then i suggest you to read it's documentation https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md. No need to download the zip if you get it with composer ;)